# Excel date format issue (00/01/1990)

Tags: excel, vba, date

I just trying to replace the 0's(Actually it is in date format =00/01/1990)  to N.A

So I have recorded the macro. I checked that macro in different file, but it is not working correctly. If I click <kbd>F2</kbd> for each cell then I try to re run the macro then it is working fine. Any other ways to skip keep pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> for each range (thousand of ranges are there) .. for ex if A1,B1,A2 and B2 have 00/01/1900 when I run the below macro its not working perfectly .. then I tried to press <kbd>F2</kbd> for each cell again re run the macro ..then its working well

Code :

```
Range("A1").Select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Replace What:="00/01/1900", Replacement:="N/A", LookAt:=xlPart _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Range("AW1").Select
```

Comment: Are you getting the results changing in the first column but not others? 00/01/1900 is not a date I am aware of, but the replacement seems to work in the code you provided. It may be if there is a space in your data that xlDown and xlRight are not selecting what you expect. Or are you seeing any results at all with your code?

Comment: Test your ranges MsgBox(Selection.End(xlToRight).Address) is it selecting what you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to replace in the entire worksheet then you can use this instead of defining your range everytime

```
Sub Sample()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells.Replace What:="00/01/1900", Replacement:="N/A", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think the answer from Siddharth Rout is probably what you're looking for, but maybe this might help too?

The dates you're looking at are really zeros, right? You could test and handle those cells in a formula in a separate column (that is if you weren't looking to automate this solution).

For example, if your dates are in column A, and this is where you're seeing the "00/01/1900" as well, just as add a formula in column B.  Something like:

```
=IF(A1=0, "N/A", A1)
```

You could then copy the results in column B and paste special their values onto column A -- effectively turning your 0's into N/A's.